# PySpark: MutableLong cannot be cast to MutableInt (no long in dataframe)

Tags: pyspark, hive, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I'm trying to read a `profiles` table from Athena in PySpark using Glue client from boto3 and checking if it's empty. Why Spark bug on converting Int to Long, knowing that I do not have Long type in the table read? There is nothing on Google, nor on StackOverflow that answers this problem.

Here is a code sum-up:

```py
dataframe = GlueContext(session.sparkContext).create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
                database="xxx",
                table_name="profiles",
                catalog_id="xxx"
            ).toDF()
if dataframe.rdd.isEmpty():
     dataframe = session.sparkContext.emptyRDD().toDF(schema)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
ERROR GlueExceptionAnalysisListener: [Glue Exception Analysis] Event: GlueETLJobExceptionEvent
[...]
  File "/myScript.py", line 246, in load_table
   if dataframe.rdd.isEmpty()
[...]
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file s3://bucket/path/to/profiles/vault=c27/subgroup=1/part-00003-a97d95f5-713c-4756-808b-38c3866842cb.c000.snappy.parquet
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableLong cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableInt
```

Here is the Athena DDL:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `profiles`(
  `id` string, 
  `anonymousids` array<string>, 
  `lastconsentinsightusage` boolean, 
  `lastconsentactivationusage` boolean, 
  `gender` string, 
  `age` int, 
  `iata` string, 
  `continent` string, 
  `country` string, 
  `city` string, 
  `state` string, 
  `brandvisit` int, 
  `knownprofileinmarket` date, 
  `devicebrowser` string, 
  `devicebrand` string, 
  `deviceos` string, 
  `returnedinmarket` date)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `vault` varchar(5), 
  `subgroup` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://bucket/path/to/profiles'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1645604528')
```

And here is the parquet schema:

```json
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "spark_schema",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "Id",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "anonymousIds",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : {
        "type" : "record",
        "name" : "list",
        "fields" : [ {
          "name" : "element",
          "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
          "default" : null
        } ]
      }
    } ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "lastConsentInsightUsage",
    "type" : [ "null", "boolean" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "lastConsentActivationUsage",
    "type" : [ "null", "boolean" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "gender",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "age",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "iata",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "continent",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "country",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "city",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "state",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "brandVisit",
    "type" : [ "null", "int" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "knownProfileInMarket",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "int",
      "logicalType" : "date"
    } ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "deviceBrowser",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "deviceBrand",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "deviceOs",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
    "default" : null
  }, {
    "name" : "returnedInMarket",
    "type" : [ "null", {
      "type" : "int",
      "logicalType" : "date"
    } ],
    "default" : null
  } ]
}
```

And a line of the parquet file:

```json
{"Id": "34e9bbcd3dd577d6bc3f9b82d9dd99666dafa0203486d2a604f59b7702d50d7d", "anonymousIds": [{"element": "5510"}], "lastConsentInsightUsage": true, "lastConsentActivationUsage": true, "gender": "F", "age": 40, "iata": "", "continent": "EU", "country": "DE", "city": "Frankfurt (Oder)", "state": "BB", "brandVisit": 9, "knownProfileInMarket": 18765, "deviceBrowser": "Googlebot", "deviceBrand": "Spider", "deviceOs": "Other", "returnedInMarket": 18765}
```

Comment: I discovered that some parquet files did not have the same schema! Sometimes, `brandvisit` column is stored as long, even if there are only integers. I'm wondering how to read this table no matter what the number type and cast it to an integer.

Comment: No proper solution found exept changing the underlayer files. Which is not a goos answer to me.